# MySQLWorkbench Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to execute the following SQL command in MySQLWorkbench but it's giving me an error.

Command:

```
ALTER TABLE `ABC`.`GroupMembers` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_PROFILES`
  FOREIGN KEY ()
  REFERENCES `ABC`.`profiles` ()
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Error:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
  REFERENCES `ABC`.`profiles` ()
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION' at line 3
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `ABC`.`GroupMembers` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_PROFILES`
  FOREIGN KEY ()
  REFERENCES `ABC`.`profiles` ()
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Not sure what's up.  This script was generated by MySQLWorkbench

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has to be a column (or columns) in both lists. Those can't be empty.

For example:

```
  FOREIGN KEY (profile_id)
  --           ^^^^^^^^^^
  REFERENCES `ABC`.`profiles` (id)
  --                           ^^
```

The datatypes of the columns much match *exhactly*. And values stored in the foreign key column must match the value in a row in the referenced table. (In this example, all values in `profile_id` must match the value of the `id` column in the `profiles` table.

Answer (score 1):

MYSQL is saying its an syntax issue, and as I can see, there is a couple of things missing in you code.

Please check this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) and learn more about the sintaxis in mysql regarding constraints.

Hope it helps.

Edit:

Ok, so just to enforce  spencer7593's answer (which should be marked as answer if it solves your issue):

```
...
/profile_id would be the name you will set to the foreign key
FOREIGN KEY (profile_id) 
...
/The references should be of the same value. 
/`table_name`.`column_name` is the referenced column
/ id is the column on the table which will hold foreign key
REFERENCES `ABC`.`profiles` (id)
```

Comment: Include the errors and solution in your answer please.

Comment: Terribly sorry for that, was trying to encourage him to understand the issue rather then fixing it for him. Wont happen again, thanks for comments.